# Converting video file m4v to NSData

Tags: video, ios7, nsdata, m4v

Can I know how to convert a video file in the format m4v to NSData and vice versa?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting video file into nsdata

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videofilepath];
```

or else video from url

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videourl];
```

Comment: Hi @Thukaram I tried that. If i print that by using the print statement it's printing the NSData. But when i use the breakpoint it shows the following message
"expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: step over. The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation".